# Solr search for matching fields

Tags: search, solr

We are trying to use Solr to search our document contents, however I want to be able to search for fields that match internally. I have looked but cannot find anything on self-referential or inner joins.

So for example:

```
<doc>
<field name="id">12345</field>
<field name="author">Smith</field>
<field name="last_edit">Smith</field>
...
</doc>
```

Obviously a (author:Smith AND last_edit:Smith) would work, but I would like to be able to search for all documents where author and last_edit are the same, not necessarily a fixed value. Defining a new field is fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [query for document that two fields are equal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258605/query-for-document-that-two-fields-are-equal)

Comment: This does answer my question, however I was trying to simplify the question, in my real data author is not single valued. However I think that the answer can still be applied by applying a editor_in_authors index.